# uibutton property to avoid highlights

Tags: iphone, uibutton

At the time of click a button it's highlighted. While click the button i want to avoid the highlighting of button.

In my Application background image for the button is square shape if i'm click the button it shows square outline of the button.but my button is customtype only....

Please help me out to solve this....

Thank you
Renya

Comment: UIButton *homebut= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
 homebut.frame = CGRectMake(100, 270, 89, 93); 
 
 
 [homebut setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startbut.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
 
[homebut addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
 [self.view addSubview:homebut];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set adjustsImageWhenHighlighted property to YES...
it will avoid the highlight of UIButton

Comment: It's the opposite that works: adjustImageWhenHighlighted to NO

Answer (score 2):

Try setting button's `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` property to `NO`

Comment: [homebut setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];    I've added this code into my application.First time click this button it's higligted.Next click it's not highlighted...why the first time it's highlighting?please help me to do this....Thank you...

Comment: I've just made a sample app with your code - it does not highlight an image... where do you set adjustsImageWhenHighlighted property in your code?

Comment: I have given this code [homebut setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO]; in ViewDidLoad method because B'coz i'm writting code for creating the button and adding the button to the view in ViewDidLoad method only...Please help me to solve this issue...Thank you

Comment: I've used exactly your code in my sample and put in viewDidLoad method as well...

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating button using Interface Builder..

Inside the button Attribute Inspector ..

On the top .. there is drop down box.. which has different states of the button 
like Default, Highlighted, Selected etc.. you can set Button's behavior here..

Comment: I'm creating the button programmatically .I tried this code [homebut setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];at the first time of click the button is highlighted and the next click it's not highlighting...What should i do to solve this issue...please help me out to do this...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding :

```
[ homebut setHighlighted:NO ];
```

?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I agree. And you can avoid to comment 2 years old post ;-)

Comment: This is part of the beta review process to go over old posts of poor quality. I didn't mean any personal offense by my critique.